# IF Boolean statement order of input validation

Tags: c#

I have to validate some inputs the user makes, and send a error message

this is what I got so far

```
// probes the methods to check for validity.
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(ValidWidth(float.Parse(txtWidth.Text))))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!(ValidLength(float.Parse(txtLength.Text))))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!(ValidDepth(float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text))))
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

My problem is when I enter the values into Length, Width, and Depth. It only does it in order..what I mean is if I don't enter a width and leave it blank and put in length and depth it gives me a unhandled expection.

here are my methods

```
/** Created a boolean method to test if the written width is valid OR not valid **/
private bool ValidWidth(float Width1) {
   float Width = float.Parse(txtWidth.Text);
    {
        if (Width >= 2 & Width <= 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            string Title = "Data Invalid";
            string Msg = "Width Measurement is invalid \n Place enter a value between 2 and 20";
            DialogResult Response;

            Response = MessageBox.Show(Msg, Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/** Created a boolean method to test if the written legnth is valid OR not valid **/
private bool ValidLength(float Length1)
{
    float Length = float.Parse(txtLength.Text);
    {
        if (Length >= 5 & Length <= 50)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            string Title = "Data Invalid";
            string Msg = "Legnth Measurement is invalid \n Place enter a value between 5 and 50";
            DialogResult Response;

            Response = MessageBox.Show(Msg, Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/** Created a boolean method to test if the written legnth is valid OR not valid **/
private bool ValidDepth(float Depth1)
{
    float Depth = float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text);
    if (Depth >= 2 & Depth <= 4)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        string Title = "Data Invalid";
        string Msg = "Average Depth Measurement is invalid \n Place enter a value between 2 and 4";
        DialogResult Response;

        Response = MessageBox.Show(Msg, Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you searched for exception message what SO posts did you find?

Comment: Before fixing that, check your validation function, they didn't use the passed  value.

Comment: You forgot the most important piece of information - actual exception. What does it contain?

Answer (score 2):

The `Parse` method will throw an exception if you feed it an empty string. You should catch that exception, or use `TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up every thing in your code. first there is a method `float.TryParse` which attempts to convert your string into float number. but it will not throw an exception if conversion failed. instead it gives a boolean value which tells parse succeeded or not.

I think this is better.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ValidateWidth(txtWidth.Text) || 
       !ValidateLength(txtLength.Text) ||
       !ValidateDepth(txtAvgDepth.Text)) // if any of these failed
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Msg, Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

I write ValidateWidth for you as an example.

```
private string Title = "Data Invalid";
private string Msg;

private bool ValidateWidth(string input)
{
    float width;

    if(float.TryParse(input, out width))
    {
        if (Width >= 2 && Width <= 20)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    Msg = "Width Measurement is invalid \n Place enter a value between 2 and 20";

    return false;
}
```

Comment: how are you returning true or false when the method is void?

Comment: @Minosum that was a mistake. it should be bool